# Magento 2 - Order assets

Tags: magento, assets

What is the best way to order a CSS file of a custom theme at the bottom of  in Magento 2. By example, I would like place CSS after or before an other.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to position your CSS files. You can however add the `media` attribute to the css element. This will add it to the end of all the included CSS in the head.

```
<head>
    <css src="css/styles.css" media="all" />
</head>
```